# How to find the accurate time of capturing a frame captured by an IP camera?

Tags: c++, opencv, ip-camera

We use an IP camera and by OpenCV, capturing frame is done.
Because of running heavy weight image processing program, sometimes capturing a frame last 50 millisecond. 
How we can find the accurate time of capturing that frame?
The accepted error is about 5 millisecond.

Comment: You should add some code

Comment: If IP camera doesn't provide this data somewhere, i.e. in picture metadata, then you can't.

Comment: `cap.get(CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with opencv doc the get public method (with option CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)of the VideoCapture class provide  Current position of the video file in milliseconds.so it dones't work for the frame that you grab from rtsp stream.